# Egit: add, commit and push in one step?

Tags: eclipse, egit

Most of the times I perform the following 3 steps when I have modified a file in eclipse that is under version control using git:

```
1) Add to index
2) Commit
3) Push
```

Is it possible when using EGit to perform the 3 above steps in one step inside eclipse? I know the two first steps can be combined:

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/12/25/git-alias-add-commit/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This became possible in the new EGit version 2.1. At the bottom of the commit dialog, you can now check the option "Push the changes to upstream".

See also: [EGit 2.1: New and Noteworthy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.1)

Answer (score -1):

This adds the modified files to staging area, then confirms, all in one step.

`git commit -am "message for commit"`

`git add file1 file2 file3 && git commit -m "message for commit"`

Comment: To quote "Soul Music" by Pratchett: "Two out of three isn't bad".